# SSH connection does not work while browsers do

Tags: linux, ssh, fedora, routing, internet

I have the following network layout: Internet comes true fiber optics to modem. From modem LAN cable goes to router. Since that router wifi signal is weak, a LAN cable goes to another router from which I connect over true wifi.

TL;DR - Modem > router > router with wifi > me.

Browser connects just fine. (I had to set up to use OpenDNS or Google (optional) DNS server since somewhy browser could not detect providers DNS; It was done in second router).

And now I tried to ssh to another IP and noticed that terminal does not have any internet connection. How comes that browser can connect while simple ping does not? I haven't changed any settings in my PC regarding connection.

I'm using Fedora 16;
Gnome 3.2.1;
Terminal - Terminator 0.96;
Google chrome 16;
FireFox 10

Comment: do you have use an http proxy ?

Comment: You had to set up DNS servers? This is strange and I'd look over there first. Try to resolve names in your terminal, if it works, try telnet-int to a webserver (port 80), this could reveal a packet filter software. If you can't resolve, you should fix this problem first (use your ISP DNS cache servers if you can, it really should be possible), how did you set it up in the first place?

Comment: "noticed that terminal does not have any internet connection"?  What error do you see when you try to ssh?  Can you ping another site, e.g. google.com?  Are you using a proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked whether one of the routers has any restrictions outbound? I don't think this is likely, as it would be a non-standard configuration, but you may have a block on traffic other than http traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Weird issue. Since the browser would be using dns resolution, I would try this in the terminal:

```
dig yahoo.com
```

If you get something like this:

```
...
;; ANSWER SECTION:
yahoo.com.      431 IN  A   98.139.180.149
yahoo.com.      431 IN  A   209.191.122.70
yahoo.com.      431 IN  A   72.30.2.43
yahoo.com.      431 IN  A   98.137.149.56
...
```

Then your terminal has internet access.

If you don't get something like above, what's in /etc/resolv.conf ?

There's no way your browser has internet access while your terminal does not.